# SELECT after INSERT statement?

Tags: java, mysql

So my issue is after I insert a new record in the database, I want to do a SELECT query that should include that new record. However, the data being returned excludes the newly added record. It seems like whenever I first open the connection, whatever is already in the database is what my program goes off. I hope this makes sense. All input is appreciated.

**Update:**

So here is the INSERT snippet

```
String DML = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTHDATE, DEATH_DATE, MARITAL_STATUS,"
+ " WEDDING_DATE, SPOUSE_NAME, MILITARY_SERVICE, DATE_JOINED, DEPARTURE_DATE, ACCEPTANCE_MODE, DEPARTURE_MODE,"
+ " RELATED_TO, NOTES) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(DML);
            pstmt.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
            pstmt.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
            pstmt.setString(3, jTextField6.getText());
            pstmt.setString(4, jTextField11.getText());
            pstmt.setString(5, jTextField3.getText());
            pstmt.setString(6, jTextField5.getText());
            pstmt.setString(7, jTextField4.getText());
            pstmt.setString(8, jTextField8.getText());
            pstmt.setString(9, jTextField7.getText());
            pstmt.setString(10, jTextField10.getText());
            pstmt.setString(11, jTextField9.getText());
            pstmt.setString(12, jTextField13.getText());
            pstmt.setString(13, jTextField14.getText());
            pstmt.setString(14, jTextArea1.getText());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            if (conn.getAutoCommit() == false)
                conn.commit();
```

Now this is the SELECT snippet which if fired after the INSERT

```
pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT CONCAT(LAST_NAME, ', ', FIRST_NAME) AS NAME FROM MEMBERS ORDER BY LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME");
        rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Well you need to post some code so that we can see how you are doing it actually..

Comment: Did you commit the changes first?

Comment: If the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` are done on two different connections, then you must [`commit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29) the `INSERT` before the `SELECT` can see it.

Comment: int rowsInserted =  pstmt.executeUpdate();  please check rowsInserted count

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that you have `autocommit` mode disabled and/or you are running the 2 queries (`INSERT` then `SELECT`) as a ***transaction***.

Try turning `autocommit` mode **on** and then running the 2 queries again (`INSERT` then `SELECT`), it should work.

Comment: I tried that and still not getting the new record. See code above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this

```
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into t1 ...");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ... from t1");
```

then data inserted in statement 1 is always visible in statement 2, both in autocommit on and off modes.

It is only possibly that select does not see inserted records if you insert in one transaction, do not commit, and read in another transaction

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be done:
You can use an `autoincrement` column say call it **serialID**.
Insert data normally. When retrieving use `MAX(serialID)`

```
SELECT CONCAT(LAST_NAME, ', ', FIRST_NAME) AS NAME FROM MEMBERS ORDER BY
LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME where serialID = (select max(serialID) from MEMBERS);
```

You'll have to do this in one transaction.